# How do I create FNaF floor tile bump using brick texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

Okay,I hope this isn't a duplicate.

Do you remember how the floor tile in FNaF has that bump to it?
[image]

Well,I want to replicate it in Cycles so I can bake it as a Bump Map for Blender Game Engine.

I haven't seen any of the tutorials,so technically I don't have a clue and I'm nowhere close to finished with my fan game.

Can someone help me,please?

Comment: So you just want to know how to do bump mapping in Cycles or is there something specific about the bump map?

Comment: There is.

What I want to do is scale the bricks horizontally so it matches the floor tile's shape.

Then I want to align the bricks into a perfect checkerboard pattern.

And finally bake it as a bump map.

Comment: You should add that into your question by using the [edit] link below your question. I think you are presuming that users of this site have a familiarity with FNaF. You are limiting the amount of users that can answer this question by not being specific with what you are asking and relying on people's familiarity with that game.

Comment: Sorry Ray.

I don't mean to confuse people.

I'll try experimenting and if it doesn't work,I'll show you guys as an example.

Comment: What you need to do is watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pcjenAfFto) and then just do it with your floor and your texture. If you want to make it so it has bumpy-ness, then you should watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzXNZkEoTAk) and then use your own textures. You can also use bump maps in the BGE. Here is a texture similar to the one that is used for the floor in FNaF: [FnaF floor texture...](http://www.textures.com/download/substance0001/125717)

Comment: I could watch this.

Comment: Only I'm using a school laptop and YouTube is blocked.

Comment: But you gave me the hint I needed all along,so thank you.